# Lock keyword not working as expected with string

Tags: c#, .net, locking

I have some code that creates a new row in a database with a given `token`, or returns the existing row if it already exists:

```
public static RunSet ProvisionRun(ApplicationDbContext context, IIdentity identity, string token, CrewType crewType)
{
   var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));
   var user = manager.FindById(identity.GetUserId());
   var runSet = user.RunSets.SingleOrDefault(r => r.RunName == token);

   if (runSet != null) // Run set already created, they must be uploading new files to this run; return existing run
      return runSet;

   // Create the run
   var newRun = new RunSet
   {
      Created = DateTime.Now,
      CrewType = crewType.ToString(),
      RunName = token,
      InputFiles = new List<RunFile>()
   };

   user.RunSets.Add(newRun);
   context.SaveChanges();

   return newRun;
}
```

This works great, however multiple threads might call this code at once resulting in multiple rows with the same `RunName` (which creates a unique constraint violation).  To avoid this, I can put a `lock` statement around this code:

```
private static readonly Object _lock = new Object();

public static RunSet ProvisionRun(ApplicationDbContext context, IIdentity identity, string token, CrewType crewType)
{
   lock (_lock)
   {
      // Same stuff here

      return newRun;
   }
}
```

This fixes the bug.  However, no two users will ever pass in the same `token` so really what I'd like to do is prevent the same *user* from calling the method, but allow two *different* users to call the method at the same time.  I should be able to lock on the user's identity:

```
lock (identity.Name) // This is a string
{
   // Same stuff here

   return newRun;
}
```

However, this doesn't work.  I've stepped through it in the debugger and indeed it just walks right through the `lock` even though `identity.Name` is the same in both threads:

[image]

I'm somewhat inclined to believe that the `lock` keyword works on exact reference equality, which would make sense.  However, digging through the [lock documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) on MSDN, it clearly says otherwise:

[image]

I'm assuming the framework has a hash of locks and will check the object equality.  It could also be the documentation is misleading, since it's using a string constant which would be interned.

Either way, it's clear that my understanding of locks has some gaps.  Anyone about to fill these in?  Thanks!

Comment: not talking about locking string but why not lock on Identity it self?

Comment: I tried that, and it has the same behavior as locking on the string.

Comment: Never lock on a string, ever! Not only can you have referential identity problems you also have lock inversion nightmares.

Comment: Thanks @EricLippert!  Can you provide a recommendation for locking only on that user?  Is using a named Mutex a good approach, or is it overkill?

Comment: @EricLippert why does a string lock cause inversions?

Comment: Looks to me like you need a database transaction, not a thread synchronization.

Comment: @JakubLortz - Yea, I think that would be the ideal solution.  Not quite sure how to do that with the Entity Framework.

Comment: I think you have to use a stored procedure. First insert where not exists, then select. Putting the current code in a transaction will not work. If you use any isolation level below serializable it will still allow 2 transactions to insert the same row, and serializable will cause deadlocks.

Comment: Cool, I'll look into that..  Thanks!

Comment: @shay__: Suppose you lock on "A" and then while still locked, you wait on "B". Meanwhile, code in the same process *in a library you didn't even write and have no knowledge of* locks on "B" and then tries to obtain a lock on "A". Now you have a deadlock. **Only lock on private objects that you control entirely**. That way no one else can be locking on that object without your knowledge.  Remember, **using shared locks correctly requires every line of code in the entire process to be written by someone who understands the locking strategy**.  This is one of many reasons why concurrency is hard.

Comment: @EricLippert thanks, this is very comprehensive! :)

Answer (score 3):

Runtime strings are not saved in the intern pool, thus have different references even if they have the same value. Precompiled strings, however, are saved in the intern pool and have the same reference when the values are the same. I tend to believe this is why your threads don't "share the same lock", the identical `Name`s values have different references.

Answer (score 1):

I have built this simple class to use in situations like yours:

```
public class NamedLock : IDisposable
{
    public NamedLock(string name)
    {
        if (name == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }
        mutex = new Mutex(false, name);
        mutex.WaitOne();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (mutex != null)
        {
            mutex.ReleaseMutex();
            mutex = null;
        }
    }

    private Mutex mutex;
}
```

Usage is as follows:

```
using(new NamedLock(identity.Name))
{
    // do some stuff
}
```

But be careful about "named mutexes":

> Because they are system-wide, named mutexes can be used to coordinate resource use across process boundaries

Regarding your problem, I'm also guessing that your strings have different references and the *lock statement* is working on reference equality instead of value equality, which makes sense to me.

Comment: All evidence points to this; yet I've found no documentation anywhere that the `lock` keyword works on reference equality.

Comment: From the [lock statement reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) it seems implicit that it works on reference equality: *The lock keyword marks a statement block as a critical section by obtaining the mutual-exclusion lock for a given object*. Since two different objects can have the same value.

Comment: Found [this post](http://blog.coverity.com/2014/02/12/how-does-locking-work/) by Eric Lippert which gets into the hard core details of locking.  Needless to say, it's *most definitely* based on the exact reference of the object.  My initial instincts were correct.  The named Mutex would definitely be a solution, but it's fairly heavy and I have my own issues with them.

Comment: Absolutely locks use reference identity. Never lock on a string or a boxed value.

Comment: @MikeChristensen You could lock on `String.Intern(identity.Name)` instead, to ensure that you always use the same reference, but I am not sure what kind of a performance hit this might cause. Alternatively, you could intern the name as you assign it to that property.

Answer (score 0):

What you're actually looking for is an atomic database operation, not thread synchronization.

Even if you make the `lock` work as you want, it will only work within one process. If you scale the application out to several servers the problem will be back.

The code will also be confusing to other developers. Nobody expects `lock` to be used to synchronize access to database table.

Unfortunately, simply wrapping the current code in a transaction will not work either. The way it's written now, it

1. Selects a row from a table
2. If no row was found, insert a new one

If you use any transaction isolation level below serializable, it will not prevent 2 transactions from inserting a new row simultaneously.

If you use serializable, you will get deadlocks as 2 transactions will acquire a shared lock for the `select` and both of them will try to get an exclusive lock for the `insert`.

To solve this problem, the whole operation should be performed as

1. Insert a new row if it doesn't exist
2. Select the row

In EF, the closest method to 1. is `AddOrUpdate`, but the 'update' part is not what you want. It seems the only option to do it is a stored procedure.

Answer (score -1):

Create a dictionary and use it to keep sync objects.

```
static Dictionary<string, object> lockMe

if(!lockMe.ContainsKey(identity.Name)) lockMe.Add(identity.Name,new Object());

lock(lockMe[identity.Name])
{}
```

EDIT: you need to sync dictionary population, so put if-Add in a lock statement.

Comment: You should use ConcurrentDictionary in your example, which is not very practical anyway, if there are millions or billions of users (hence keys).

Comment: In my experience ConcurrentDictionary is slow. Millions of users meanch a bunch on MBytes, billions is not realistic.

Comment: 1) `ConcurrentDictionary` is **MUCH** better than using locks to synchronize `Dictionary` accesses. 2) I wasn't talking about memory usage, i was talking about lock contentions.